# Got fetch error timeout when using getServerSideProps in production

Tags: next.js, pre-rendering

i'm trying to popualte my page to seo using getServerSideProps and it's working fine in Development but in production it gives fetch error timeout
FetchError: request to API failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

```
// lib/fetchData.js

export const GetData = async (id) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`api?id=${id}`, {
            method: 'Get',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            agent,
        })
        const data = await res.json()
        return data

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

//in /myPage 
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    const data = await GetData(query.DetailedCampaign)
    console.log('data', data);
    return { props: { metaDetails: await data?.Data[0] } }
}
```

edit

I tried this way also and got the same issue it works fine in development and time out in production

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query }) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`https://internalApi?id=${query.id}`, {
            method: 'Get',
            agent: httpsAgent,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        return { props: { metaDetails: data?.Data[0] } };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return { props: { metaDetails: null } };
    }
}
```

Comment: If its an internal api route, i dont think you can do that, move the logic directly into getServerSideProps instead, if its an external api, then idk you have to provide some more info

Comment: yes i'm using internal api and i put the logic into getServerSideProps  and i face the same issue timeout ... what info do you need to solve this issue I'm trying to solve this issue from 2 weeks ago

Comment: do whatever the api does in getServerSideProps instead

Comment: @ChrisLi I did and I even removed the agent but I got the same error I edited the question with the new code